# How to position the tooltip to display entire content without having to scroll down the page to see the entire content

Tags: html, css

```
<a class="ctooltip" tooltip="Definition:1000 characters here 
onclick="openDocumentTypeHistory(2110)" href="#" >mytestdocument</a>
```

my css function

```
.ctooltip{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
              .ctooltip:hover:after{
    background: #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 2px;
        border-color: #000000;
        border-style: ridge;
        border-width: 1px;
        top: 26px;
        text-decoration: none;
    color: #1d3030; 
    left: 20%;
        content: attr(tooltip);
    padding: 5px 15px;
         position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
        width: 220px;
       max-width: 220px;
}
       a:hover {text-decoration: none; }
```

i wanna display the entire tooltip message which is 1000 characters long without having the user to scroll down the page to see the tooltip content

Answer (score 0):

Just increase your tooltip width. 1000 characters are take too much height with `220px` width. so you just need to increase your tooltip width for reduce height.

Comment: If I want it to position above? I mean if the tooltip is at the end of page,it's making me scroll down to see the entire tooltip message?

Comment: For this purpose, the easiest way is that, you can use bootstrap tooltip (without placement) or bootstrap popover.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips , http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: i don't want to use any javascripts.I prefer proper css!